# 'HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized' Unable to use Deta Base

Tags: python, database, fastapi

I am using Deta Base to create a API using the Fast API framework.
I was able deploy my API using deta micros, it worked like a dream.

However, when I am trying to use the 'Deta Base' feature, It is giving me the following error:

```
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

I have logged in in the terminal already, this was the result.

```
deta login
Logged in successfully.
```

I have checked that my project key is correct, I also made a new project and copied and pasted the id directly in, so I am sure that my project key is linked to a Deta project.

This is my code.

```
# python-decouple
from decouple import config
DETA_PROJECT_KEY = config('DETA-PROJECT-KEY')
DETA_PROJECT_ID = config('DETA-PROJECT-ID')
DETA_BASE_NAME = config('DETA-BASE-NAME')

# Deta Base
from deta import Deta
deta = Deta('DETA-PROJECT-KEY')
locations_of_interest = deta.Base('locations_of_interest')

locations_of_interest.insert({"hello":"world"})
new_home = next(locations_of_interest.fetch({"hello":"world"}))
```

How can I fix this?

Thank you for your help!!

Comment: I don't know what deta is, but are you sure deta = Deta('DETA-PROJECT-KEY') is correct? It looks like you are passing a string, not the actual key. I have never used it, just a guess

Comment: Checkout deta.sh

Comment: @Isabi that was it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from looking at your code, I could identify the issue that you are passing a string instead of the actual project key, try fixing that by replacing `'DETA-PROJECT-KEY'` with `DETA_PROJECT_KEY` as follows:

```py
deta = Deta(DETA_PROJECT_KEY)
```

If this issue persists, feel free to reach out to us (the Deta team) on Discord/Slack/Intercom, we're happy to help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured that for the http api, put/post should be sent to
[https://database.deta.sh/v1/{project_id}/{base_name}/items](https://database.deta.sh/v1/%7Bproject_id%7D/%7Bbase_name%7D/items)
and not just to
[https://database.deta.sh/v1/{project_id}/{base_name}/](https://database.deta.sh/v1/%7Bproject_id%7D/%7Bbase_name%7D/)